# Azure APP GW infront of API Manager (without VNET)

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

Anyone know of a guide on how to but APP GW infront of APIM, should be possible but cant figure out how (or not sure how to setup APP GW).

thx

Comment: keep getting this error: 

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
                    <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly this same issue and seems there is not a way of having an exposed APIM to put in front of it one APP GW. What is pretty annoying.
The only way I find is to put APIM in a internal VNET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually forward traffic from Application Gateway to API Management with VNET configuration set to 'None'

1. Normally add your listener
2. Add your backend pool with the default FQDN (xxx.azure-api.net) of the API Management
3. Add a heath probe pointing to xxx.azure-api.net/status-0123456789abcdef
4. Add a HTTPS backend setting with Backend authentication certificate with Use for App service set 'yes' and a custom probe the aforementioned.
5. Add a rule combining all the above and a path based rule with just a '/'

This is all you need.

In order to expose management and developer portal through application gateway you need all the above but the health probes should point to xxx.portal.azure-api.net/signin and xxx.management.azure-api.net/ServiceStatus accordingly